# CI Build not triggered?

Tags: azure-pipelines

Been a while since using the azure devops build system and just now getting familiar with the yaml file. Ok, so starting a new build, I selected the .net desktop template, chose my repo to build and was presented with a yaml file, which I stored in the master branch.  I changed the trigger branch to

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - dev
```

Questions:
(1) as a test, I edited a file in my **dev** branch, committed the changes, but no build job was run.  What can I check?
(2) Does the yaml file need to be in the same branch as where the build pulls code from?
(3) Does the trigger branch pull code from that same branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The azure pipeline file must exist in the branch being triggered since Source Control is isolated to that branch.  It can exist in both;however, given your trigger only on the dev  branch check in to dev will trigger the pipeline running against the dev branch.

The trigger branch will pull code automatically from that branch.  However; a manual run can be done and pointed to a separate branch.  It will run the version of the pipeline yml IN THAT BRANCH.

[image]